# NginX multiple domains NOT working

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, domain

In my DigitalOcean droplet, I'm trying to use my NginX to host multiple websites on the same droplet. 
I can access *test.domain1.com* and *domain1.com* with or without the use of *default_server* tag. However, accessing *domain2.com* just presents the contents of *domain1.com* (the server block with the default_server tag) without forwarding the url to *domain1.com* in the browser.
I've checked for typo in my configs but can't find one. Secondly, neither the access.log nor the error.log have any issues.

The **hostname** of my droplet is domain1.com.
I've created **2 DNS entries**: 1 for domain1.com and the other for domain2.com. Both have the same A and CNAME records.

`@      A      ip.add.re.ss
www    CNAME  @
*      CNAME  @`

My configs are:
*/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:*
http://pastebin.com/AWf5EM66
*/etc/nginx/global/wordpress.conf:*
http://pastebin.com/Uc9KSqhh
*/etc/nginx/global/restrictions.conf:*
http://pastebin.com/cLfMv6jC

*/etc/nginx/sites-available/sites.conf:*

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/domain1_test;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name test.domain1.com;

    include global/restrictions.conf;
    include global/wordpress.conf;

}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/domain2.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.domain2.com;

    include global/restrictions.conf;
    include global/wordpress.conf;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/domain1.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.domain1.com;

    include global/restrictions.conf;
    include global/wordpress.conf;
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: I'm guessing you have only www.domain2.com in server_name in the site vhost but you are trying to access it without www ?

Comment: Yes, this seemed to be the problem. I now added the extra server block with return directive to take care of www.

Comment: Added an answer with this so it can be documented well.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you do not have a server with the domain2.com as server_name, only www.domain2.com. Either add domain2.com as server_name to the same server as www.domain2.com, either create another server for domain2.com that redirects to www.domain2.com using return.